# Can typealias be Codable?

Tags: swift, codable

I have a root object that consists mainly of an array of tuples and then a bunch of state enums. The tuples are described this way:

```
typealias Program = [(Number, Statement)]
```

The root object is currently NSCoding, but I'd like to add Codable to make the switch to JSON. In most cases, making the various parts become Codable requires nothing more than adding `, Codable` to their declarations, but that's not working for the tuples. I think this is just a syntax issue, but neither of these work:

```
typealias Program, Codable = [(Number, Statement)]
typealias Program = [(Number, Statement)], Codable
```

Is this possible? The [horrible documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) only mentions typealias when describing the protocol itself, and perhaps my Google-fu is failing, but I'm not seeing cogent references here on SO.

UPDATE: root object(s):

```
typealias Program = [(Number, Statement)]

public enum InterpreterState: Int, Codable {
    case Idle
    case ReadingStatement // while parsing code
    case Running          // while running it
    case ReadingInput     // while waiting on user input
}

public final class Interpreter: NSObject, NSCoding {
    /// Array of program lines
    var program: Program = Array()

    /// State
    var state: InterpreterState = .Idle
```

etc.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and post your json and your root object declaration

Comment: Ahh. I have no JSON yet, because it's not Codable. I'll add the root object...

Comment: Tuples are not codable. You would need to provide your own encoding and decoding methods

Comment: How does one add a method to a tuple? Or is there no way to do this in Swift?

Comment: `struct Number: Codable  {}

struct Statement : Codable {}

public final class Interpreter: Codable {
    public enum State: Int, Codable {
        case idle, readingStatement, running, readingInput
    }
    struct Program: Codable {
        let number: Number
        let statement: Statement
    }
    /// Array of program lines
    var programs: [Program] = []
    /// State
    var state: State = .idle
}`

Comment: But that's not a tuple. But if tuples simply can't do it I guess I'll refactor. That seems sad, but oh well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tuples are not `Codable`. If you think about it, what should the keys for `(Number, Statement)` be? (I might have made it sound like named tuples are codable, but they aren't either)

Create your own struct:

```
    struct ProgramLine: Codable {
        let lineNumber: Number // assuming these types are codable
        let statement: Statement
    }
```

And then your type alias will be codable too (without you doing anything)!

```
    typealias Program = [ProgramLine]
```

Comment: I think the keys could be easily hashed. It appears the reason is that the Swift team wants tuples to be base types and thus they can't easily conform to protocols. C'est la vie.